Remote desktop connections from Windows to stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.10
Remote desktop from Windows/Mac to Linux stopped working after updating to 24.10. This used to work on 24.06. The following error appears inside the .xorgxrdp.10.log file:
[ 85458.384] expected xrdp client_info version 20230425, got 20210723
[ 85458.384] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[ 85458.384] (EE) Incompatible xrdp version detected  - please recompile(EE)
[ 85458.384] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[ 85458.384] (EE) Please also check the log file at ".xorgxrdp.10.log" for additional information.
[ 85458.384] (EE)
[ 85458.385] rdpmouseControl: what 4
[ 85458.385] rdpkeybControl: what 4
[ 85458.385] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 85458.385] rdpLeaveVT:
[ 85458.385] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

The message seems to indicate the client version is older than expected. I updated the remote desktop app on mac/windows but I keep getting this same error in the log:
[131068.505] expected xrdp client_info version 20230425, got 20210723

Running X.Org X Server 1.21.1.13
Any advice would be appreciated.

It seems you're running quite an old version of xrdp. Did you try upgrading xrdp to the latest version (sudo apt upgrade xrdp)?

Looks like my system thinks I have the latest version...
%sudo apt upgrade xrdp
xrdp is already the newest version (0.9.24-5).

We should wait for this bug to fixed. Any other people who were hit by this bug, please follow: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xrdp/+bug/2085347

I ran into this about 15 minutes ago a little hacky but a workaround none the less:

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources by adding oracular-proposed next to oracular-backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xrdp/oracular-proposed

The service will restart and you should be able to RDP without issues.

It's working now after updating xrdp/oracular-proposed to (0.10.1-2). Thanks!

after spending three hours trying to debug my xrdp settings to no avail - this totally did the trick.  Good karma upon you!

One other comment, it took a reboot and my Win10x64 RDP client did not work until I had to accept the new "certificate" so it recognized the machine.  Once that happened, everything worked wonderfully.

I followed the first two steps, but sudo apt install xrdp/oracular-proposed returns an error: Package xrdp is not available, but is referred to by another package... Release 'oracular-proposed' for 'xrdp' was not found . Is there something else that needs to be done first?

Unfortunately this solution does not work. My system is aarch64, but I think it is the same for other architectures too.

I had trouble using the oracular-proposed package Justin Oberdorf recommended, so I took the other approach: I manually installed an older version of xorgxrdp and then I was able to RDP in.
Steps:

wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/640882094/xorgxrdp_0.9.19-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xorgxrdp_0.9.19-1_amd64.deb
xorgxrdp_0.9.19-1_amd64.deb


Are you sure you are running 24.10?

Yes, it was a clean install of 24.10 from the ISO

This worked for me. Thanks! The normal 24.10 xrdp package needs to be installed first, then install this to downgrade the 0.10.x version.
